# What does Fabric's `hide("everything")` actually hide?

Tags: python, fabric

When I use the `hide("everything")` context manager, and a fabric task fails, I still get a message. The [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/output_controls.html) read:

> **everything**: Includes warnings, running, user and output (see above.) Thus, when turning off everything, you will only see a bare minimum of output (just status and debug if it’s on), along with your own print statements.

But this is not strictly true, right? -- I see status, debug, and abort messages.

If I really do want to hide everything, is there a better way than:

```
with hide("aborts"), hide("everything"):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, look at the source:

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/context_managers.py#L98

here is the actual declaration. `everything` is pretty much everything: `warnings, running, user, output, exceptions`

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/state.py#L411

It's just a nice wrapper around `output`. Frankly i would stick to their build-in decorators since that has less chances of changing, plus you get the added value of more pythonic-readable code:

```
@task
def task1():
    with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr'):
        run('ls /var/www')
        ....
```

vs.

```
@task
def task1():
    output['running'] = False
    output['stdout'] = False
    output['stderr'] = False
    # or just output['everything'] = False
    run('ls /var/www')
    ....
```

BUT, at the end of the day its the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have always used:

```
from fabric.state import output

output['everything'] = False
```